# Browser Error: "Refused to set unsafe header 'User Agent'"

Tags: javascript, error, chrome, ajax-toolkit, browser

Just today I started having a very odd layout issue on our standard Account layout.  The org in on the NA6 server.  This is the standard layout.  It's always happening when I use chrome. I haven't been able to recreate it in IE, and get it intermittently in Firefox, but definitely it is the worst in Chrome, as it always produces this error.  My version is current

[image]

The related lists all seem to be in only the right side of a 2 column set up, as seen below

[image]

When I check the console I see the error

> Refused to set unsafe header 'User Agent'

[image]

I look further into it in the console and it appears to be an issue with the SF javascript. In particular the sforce.Transport function.   See the errors below

[image]

I have opened a ticket with SF and they are investigating, but just curious if anyone else has seen this today, or in the past.

This just started happening this morning.

Comment: It is happening again on the new version #32 of chrome. Do you know if is there any patch?

Comment: I am having the same issue with latest version of Safari and Chrome. An ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure it's related, but I noticed this on twitter:

> .@salesforce users please update your Google Chrome to 31.0.1650.57. This fixes the display issue. [Nate Lipke](https://twitter.com/EvilN8/status/401094590758780928)

I think this comes back to the known issue: [Unexpected display issue after updating to Google Chrome 31 with embedded Visualforce Pages](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T1LRAA0)

Comment: You are correct, I had to get the latest version.  Must be a pretty recent patch.  I had to clear the cache and quit out of chrome, then it automatically updated the version.  No more errors.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: There was an email alert today about this about v31 chrome.  A second alert reported google had patched the issue.

Comment: This seems to be a different issue - the v31 chrome issue was around embedded visualforce and scontrols in page layouts. I hit the issue described here with the AJAX toolkit (connection.js) a year ago and had to patch connection.js: https://github.com/capeterson/Grey-Tab/commit/04ec3c2360d29e9419b768e1633a96421e940d42#diff-3b5bd2a0f575f66ea88f9b6d5a0d618bR598

Answer (score 0):

A Way to solve this problem is to make and static resource with the connection.js file and comment the line:
//this.connection.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "SFAJAX 1.0");

Then reference the static resource, this solved my issue and the console is clear of this error.

my two cents.