# Getting some odd javascript errors on a VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have a fairly simple Visual Force page: a bunch of inputFields, inputText, etc...  A couple of RemoteAction calls - and it works well - no complaints.

However, when I load the page, in Chrome's console, I get a bunch of errors that seemed to do with js being served by Salesforce.  Is there something I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? See [Browser Error: “Refused to set unsafe header 'User Agent'”](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20748/browser-error-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-user-agent)

Comment: @DanielBallinger The latest.  31.0.1650.57 m

Comment: Do you get this error if you change to a later toolkit version, such as 29.0? You may just need to change versions.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is a red herring. It won't prevent the request from sending. The second error says that you're missing a session ID. That happens from time to time with the AJAX Toolkit. The usual fix is to add this line of code after it has been included:

```
<script>
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
</script>
```

This should fix your error.

Comment: Nope.  Didn't have any effect.  I think maybe the issue is that the POST url it says /u/24.0, but the page is version 28.  Not sure if that's a red herring too.

Comment: Try using the following script: `sforce.debug.trace = true;` This should enable the debug window.

Comment: Ok, I've done that and I got the debug window, like you said.  I got the following there: http://pastebin.com/jvKxLxAv

Comment: @AngryHacker That's interesting. Your SOAP is missing namespaces. By the way, delete that pastebin, your login could be hijacked if you're not using IP locking.

Comment: @AngryHacker I'm going to look into this for you. And your session ID is safe with me.

Comment: @AngryHacker Your session ID is literally invalid. I'm not sure how you're arriving at this point, but I have a working soap message that works with my session ID, but doesn't work with your session ID. Perhaps your IP address changed and/or your session has expired? I'm not sure why your page would have an old API token, though.

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting an old Session ID.  I've rebooted the computer and I still get the same issue.

Comment: @AngryHacker I'd love to help you more, but I'm afraid without a reliable repro, it's going to be difficult. Can you post your page's code or email it to me?

Comment: Sure, no problem.  Here is the page: http://pastebin.com/HNXBVKPQ and here is the controller/extention: http://pastebin.com/6rx6sWiD